# Optimization of AngularJS function to load images on the page

Tags: javascript, angular.js

I have two AngularJS function in my `dataContext` object that receive data from a WebAPI:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var serviceId = 'datacontext';
angular.module('app').factory(serviceId,
    ['common', datacontext]);

function datacontext(common) {
    var service = {

        getAllTagsByHttp: getAllTagsByHttp,
        getBlogPostsByHttp: getBlogPostsByHttp,
        getAllUserPicByHttp: getAllUserPicByHttp

    };
    return service;

    function getAllTagsByHttp() {
       return common.$http.get('/api/TagApi/alltags');         
    }

    function getBlogPostsByHttp() {
        return common.$http.get('/api/BlogPostApi/AllBlogPosts');
    }

    function getAllUserPicByHttp() {
        return common.$http.get('/api/BlogPostApi/AllUserPic');
    }   
}})();
```

I have an AngularJS controller that calls these API functions from the datacontext to receive information to display back to the user. The `getblogPost` function is called first because the next function needs the data from this to operate on.  The second function does a comparison on the first function's data to display back the img source to the user.

The problem I am having is that it takes quite a few seconds for the second function to receive the data and complete its operation. The amount of data being send back is a few  records.  Is there any improvements that can be made to the controller or `dataContext` object to reduce the time or improve the code?

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var controllerId = 'search';
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller(controllerId, ['common','datacontext', search]);

function search(common, datacontext) {
    var getLogFn = common.logger.getLogFn;
    var log = getLogFn(controllerId);


    var vm = this;
    vm.title = 'search';
    vm.picData = [];

    activate();

    function activate() {
        var promises = [getBlogPosts(), getUserPicData(), getUserPicUrl()];
        common.activateController(promises, controllerId)
            .then(function () { log('Search View'); });
    }

    function getBlogPosts() {
        datacontext.getBlogPostsByHttp().then(function (response) {
            vm.data = response.data;               
        });
    }
    function getUserPicData() {
        datacontext.getAllUserPicByHttp().then(function (response) {
            vm.picData = response.data;

            for (var i = 0; vm.data.length > i; i++) {
                for (var x = 0; vm.picData.length > x; x++) {
                    if (vm.data[i].UserName == vm.picData[x].UserName) {
                        vm.data[i].PictureUrl = vm.picData[x].PictureUrl;
                       // console.log(vm.data[i].PictureUrl);
                        break;
                    }

                }                   
           }
        });
    }

   function getUserPicUrl(username) {
        getUserPicData();
        for (var i = 0; vm.picData.length < i; i++) {
            if (vm.picData[i].UserName === username) {
                return vm.picData[i].PictureUrl;
                }
            }
            return "not found";      
    }
}})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would create a 4th service that returns all data in 1 go and be done with it.

Other than, I would return the array in the first block immediately. Secondly, I would probably go for object notation for something that simple:

```
function datacontext(common) {
    return {
        getAllTagsByHttp: function getAllTagsByHttp() {
          return common.$http.get('/api/TagApi/alltags');         
        },
        getBlogPostsByHttp: function getBlogPostsByHttp() {
          return common.$http.get('/api/BlogPostApi/AllBlogPosts');
        },
        getAllUserPicByHttp:     function getAllUserPicByHttp() {
          return common.$http.get('/api/BlogPostApi/AllUserPic');
        }
    };
}
```

Furthemore, for this part: *The problem i am having is that it takes quite a few seconds for the second function to receive the data and an complete its operation.* You really should use the Chrome Developer Tools (or their Firefox counterpart) and figure out what is taking so long ? ( Latency, server side processing, or JavaScript processing ). If the problem is on the server side then it makes even more sense to have only 1 API call (that's what Netflix does)